# Not getting groups data from native contacts app in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone

I am able to get groups in simulator using the below code:

```
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>

ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef groups = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllGroups(addressBook);
CFIndex numGroups = CFArrayGetCount(groups);
```

In simulator getting groups as Friends,Work  where as in device(ios7) groups array is empty.

In device(ios7) native contacts app groups are like FACEBOOK,on my iPhone .How to get these groups data ?

Comment: Did you link the Accounts Framework?

Comment: yes..edited the question and added frameworks to the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually FACEBOOK and on my iPhone are not groups,confirmed by creating a new group programmatically and by using above code groups array contains newly created one.